# Make Chapter Titles link to Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm using the `hyperref` package to create hyperlinks in my document. The links from the TOC->chapters/sections work great, but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically insert hyperlinks from section titles BACK to the TOC (section->TOC). For easier two-way navigation (especially when clicking on an incorrect link in the TOC).

In case it matters I'm working in the `report` class, and this is a (minimized) version of what I have now.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
First page

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

Blank page

\clearpage
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

Here's one possible solution using the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism;
`\hyperlink`s are conveniently added using a redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` and a redefinition of `\@chapter` was used to place the corresponding `\hypertarget`s:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\string\hypertarget{chap\thechapter}{#1}}%
\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
  \@afterheading
\fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \hyperlink{chap\thechapter}{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Three}

\end{document}
```

Here's the same idea using this time the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package with its `explicit` option to place the `\hyperlink`s:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}  
  {\Huge\hyperlink{chap\thechapter}{#1}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-22pt}  
  {\Huge#1}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\string\hypertarget{chap\thechapter}{#1}}%
\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
  \@afterheading
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Three}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

use `\hypertarget`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents

\chapter{\protect\hyperlink{chap:\thechapter}{My chapter}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{chap:\thechapter}{}}

\chapter{\protect\hyperlink{chap:\thechapter}{My chapter}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{chap:\thechapter}{}}

foo     
\end{document}
```