# Linking the section titles to toc using only hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

How to link section titles back to toc? I want to use *only* `hyperref` and not any toc related packages (answer with `titlesec` can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc))

I can do the `hypertarget` to toc sections ([answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32499/59163) provided by cmhughes and shown in the MWE below). Thus, my question really is: where to put the `hyperlink` line?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter to act as a Link}
\section{A Section to act as a Link}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60830/make-chapter-titles-link-to-table-of-contents)?

Comment: If he do not update the package in 24hours, should he donate something?

Comment: You said below that you are developing your own class. Package `hyperref` should be loaded last (there are some exceptions). Think about how you are going to deal with that. This is a very important thing and if you don't take care of any possible solution, something is about to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{\smash{\raisebox{1em}{\hypertarget{toc#4}{}}}#2}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand\mychapter[1]{%
    \chapter[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocchapter.\thechapter}{#1}}}
\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
    \section[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}}
\newcommand\mysubsection[1]{%
    \subsection[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mychapter{A Chapter to act as a Link}
        \mysection{A Section to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
        \mysection{A Section to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
    \mychapter{A Chapter to act as a Link}
        \mysection{A Section to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
        \mysection{A Section to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
            \mysubsection{A Subection to act as a Link}
    \clearpage~
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, not really. I am working on my own class file. Thus, the command that creates the link must be `\section`.

Comment: @Mappi I am a bit confused here. You say you are developing a class, which requires some experience. But above you wrote that you are a novice. Sounds pretty contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, one would just use an `\apptocmd` command (from `etoolbox` package) or `\xapptocmd` (from `xpatch` package) in order to hook the appropiate hypertarget/hyperlink command, but unfortunately, this breaks due to the definition of the structuring commands (such as `\part`, `\chapter` etc.)

A generic 'slight' redefinition of those commands provides this, however. At first, a generic structuring command is used, at the begin of a document, a loop of the (seven) commands defines those commands and adds the link. Otherwise, those commands behave as their original definitions (therefore, `\LaTeXStandardpart` etc. has to be defined, via a loop and using `\csletcs` command).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[final,pdftex]{hyperref}%

\listgadd{\StructureCommandsList}{}%


\newcommand{\LetLaTeXStandardSectionCommand}[1]{%
  \csletcs{LaTeXStandard#1}{#1}%
}%

\makeatletter%

\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\phantomsection\hypertarget{document::toc}{}}{}{}%

\newcommand{\redefinestructurecommands}[1]{%
  \csgdef{unstarred#1@@noopt}##1{%
    \csuse{unstarred#1@@opt}[##1]{##1}%
  }%

  \csgdef{unstarred#1@@opt}[##1]##2{%
    \csuse{LaTeXStandard#1}[##1]{\hyperlink{document::toc}{##2}}%
  }%


  \csgdef{unstarred#1}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \@nameuse{unstarred#1@@opt}%
    }{%
      \@nameuse{unstarred#1@@noopt}%
    }%
  }%

  \csgdef{starred#1@@noopt}##1{%
    \csuse{LaTeXStandard#1}*{\hyperlink{document::toc}{##1}}%
  }%


  \csgdef{unstarred#1}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \csuse{unstarred#1@@opt}%
    }{%
      \csuse{unstarred#1@@noopt}%
    }%
  }%

  \csgdef{#1}{%
    \@ifstar{%
      \csuse{starred#1@@noopt}%
    }{%
      \csuse{unstarred#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\makeatother


\newcommand{\RedefineStructuringCommands}{%
   % If some of the structuring commands should not use linking back to toc, just remove them from this csv - list here (say for subparagraph))
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd{\StructureCommandsList}}{part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}%
  \forlistloop{\LetLaTeXStandardSectionCommand}{\StructureCommandsList}%
  \forlistloop{\redefinestructurecommands}{\StructureCommandsList}%
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RedefineStructuringCommands%
}%


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}% For demo only
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}% For demo only

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Introduction}%

\tableofcontents%

\part{First part}%
\chapter{First chapter}%
\section{First Section}%
\section*{First starred section}%
\subsection{First subsection}%
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}%
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}%

\end{document}
```

I omitted a screenshot, as it does not reveal really anything.

**Note:** The above redefinition command `\redefinestructurecommand` is part of an yet to be published package, it's usually longer and more sophisticated ;-)

Comment: @Mappi - The only real package that's loaded in this answer is `hyperref`. (The commands of the `etoolbox` package are used only to patch existing macros.) In particular, `titlesec` is *not* loaded. I thought that not loading `titlesec` was the only real constraint.

Comment: @Mappi: I think, elegance is a term somewhat arguable ;-) As Mico stated: You did not write, that only `hyperref` is allowed until some 40 minutes ago. I can readily delete my solution and use my code for other purposes ;-)

Comment: @Mappi - Your requirement that `hyperref` be the only additional package allowed is puzzling, the more so because you also want any solution to be "elegant". Note that Christian's use of the `etoolbox` package is (basically) confined to that package's high-level macros `\apptocmd` and `\csgdef`. For all intents and purposes, Christian's answer *could* be re-written using only the low-level TeX primitives that were used to construct the two high-level macros. But nothing would be gained -- certainly not elegance. The macros of the `etoolbox` package are well debugged -- why not use them?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your support. I can live without acceptance of my answer, if there are better ones. I will try to rewrite with more low-level approaches, for my own purposes.

Comment: @Mappi: You could have readily asked about the solution before rejecting it, about `etoolbox` features  etc.

Comment: @Mappi: The solution is long, because it provides for any structuring command, not only `section` and `chapter`, even more, for yet to be defined commands as well. In this sense, it's elegant ;-) The most of it are demo

Answer (score 0):

I think this was something I was after for. Thank you Symbol 1 for the idea!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \oldsection[#1]{\protect\hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter to act as a Link}
\section{A Section to act as a Link}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). But I wonder whether you can accept your answer, technically. I have never tried it before.

Comment: @Mappi: You never said, that you only want to have only chapter and sections linked.

Comment: @Mappi: Try you solution with some starred section (of course, not to appear in toc, no hyperlink), such as `\section*{This should not be in ToC}` or with `\section[In ToC]{Not in Toc}` You will be astonished ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Good point! Either case does not really matter where I need it though.

Comment: @Mappi: Then it's not a problem, unless you don't plan to do the same for chapters as well ;-) You might have a problem then...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Do you know how to write a similar `\renewcommand` to chapter? Now I have solved the chapter part by editing `\def\@makechapterhead#`

Comment: @Mappi: It must be a nice looking code, redefining that command and that command, turning a screw here, turning a screw there ... I wonder, if you publish your class one day;-)